# Notion of solution of pde

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's consider the following Schrodinger equation
$$iu_t+\Delta u+F(u)=0$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In Cazenave's book, "Semilinear Schrodinger equation", he defines $H^1$-weak solution as $u\in L^\infty(0,T;H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))\cap W^{1,\infty}(0,T;H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ such that the equation $iu_t+\Delta u+F(u)=0$ is satisfied in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does it imply that the equation is satisfied in the space of distribution $D'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the sense
$$\int u[i\varphi_t+\Delta\varphi]+<F(u),\varphi>_{D'(\mathbb{R}^n),D(\mathbb{R}^n)}=0$$

Comment: If the equation is satisfied in $H^{-1}$, it means that is is satisfied when integrated against any function in $H^1$ and formally integrated by parts to remove the Laplacian. Since $D\subset H^1$, the answer is yes.

Comment: My doubt is the following: let's consider for instance the term $u_t$; in $H^{-1}$ it is the distribution $<u_t,\varphi>_{H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n),H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, with $\varphi\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The restriction of this distribution to $D(\mathbb{R}^n)$ coincides with the distribution $<u_t,\varphi>_{D'(\mathbb{R}^n),D(\mathbb{R}^n)}=-\int u\varphi_t$?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the underlying spaces? I thought originally that $\phi$ is independent of $t$, and you test the solution on each time slice separately (since you mentioned $H^{-1}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $D'(\mathbb R^n)$ as test function spaces), but it seems that this is perhaps not what you meant. Did you mean that the Schrödinger equation is in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with one dimension for time?

Comment: I mean that the equation is satisfied in the mentioned spaces for almost every $t\in (0,T)$.

Comment: But then the test function only lives on $\mathbb R^n$ (since you test on one time slice at a time) and you cannot integrate by parts with respect to time. In that formulation $\phi$ is independent of time. The statement is true if you replace $u\phi_t$ with $u_t\phi$ in the last equation (I originally read it this way) as I stated in my first comment.

Comment: @Joonas Maybe it's possible to choose test functions of the form $\varphi=\alpha(t)\psi(x)$ with $\alpha\in D(0,T)$ and $\psi\in D(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and perfome integration by part to get the result (using the density of such functions into $D([0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: That could work, but then it's not really testing on each time slice separately. But why do you want to integrate by parts w.r.t. time anyway? By assumption $u_t\in H^{-1}$ for almost all $t$, so I see no obvious reason for it. I suggest editing your question so that the formulation (of the assumed $H^{-1}$ weak solution and the desired $D'$ weak solution) is precise and you give some motivation for it. At the moment it is unclear what you really want to ask.

Comment: The linear part of the equation $iu_t+\Delta u$ is easy to define for a distribution. However, taking $F(u)=u^2$ would require essentially that $u(t)$ belongs to an algebra, which is not the case for $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ when $n\ge 2$: this means that I do not understand how the equation could make sense without some additional assumptions of regularity for $u$, e.g. $H^{\epsilon +n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$.